# Bent's rule: electronegativity and s character

Tags: orbitals, hybridization, electronegativity

I'm very much confused about Bent's rule. What I perceive from it is that more electronegative element occupies a position which has less s character.

What I can infer from here is that s character is inversely proportional to electronegativity which is not true. Please do explain.